# How to migrate data from one product to another without revealing database structure?

Tags: data-migration

What is best way to best way to migrate data from one product to another if both software companies refuse to reveal the database structure to one another?

Comment: I don't understand how they could come to the conclusion that the database *structure* is somehow more "valuable" than the data itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dump the data to a csv and hand it to the other company. A good DBA can take the data and write a sufficient import script that maps them to the correct datatypes on the other end.

Comment: chances are unless the application the second company is using is totally different they should have a pretty good idea what data needs to go where.

Answer (score 3):

Define some database structure capable of holding all the relevant information (it doesn't need to be optimized in any way), have the first company dump their data into that and the second one import it.

Answer (score 1):

morse code? smoke signals? braille?

really, it sounds like an untenable situation between two parties that have no confidence in once another and sounds poisonous.

Comment: Maybe they won't have to work with one another again? (Right …) I'd imagine company A has been doing the data center for customer C so far and customer C wants to move to company B now. A and B being competitors, they don't really want to tell one another the details of how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Holy smoke. Sounds like great fun of yours ;-).

Just some ideas:

If you have access to the database... for a good dba the migration should be no problem at all.

Another way would be that one company creates views to hide the underlaying datastructures and the other company can import those views.

Otherwise just let them dump the data into flat files and import those files.